# Angular – Simple Typewriter Effect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is [a beautiful typewriter directive already written](http://codepen.io/capelo/pen/Bmbgn), but I'm looking for something more simple, that just adds each letter after an interval.  I can't get this to work.  It shows the text all at once.  Something is wrong with the $timeout.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
var time = 1000;
var addLetter = function(i) {
    $scope.string2 = $scope.string.substr(0, i);
};
for (var i = 0, len = $scope.string.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(time) {
        $timeout(function() {
            addLetter(i);
        }, (time + 300));
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate way.

```
var content = "contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent";

$scope.type = "";
var i=0;

var timer = $interval(function(){
    if(i<content.length)
        $scope.type += content[i];
      else
        $interval.cancel(timer);

     i++; 
     $scope.$apply();
}, 100);
```

Credit:  https://gist.github.com/frozonfreak/8018689

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BILaWVuNpao2zcIInXLl?p=preview

Comment: I updated it to use the angular $interval and to cancel it when done.

Comment: Beautiful, much better!  Thanks for your help lucuma!

Comment: Rather than using the if/else block, just pass `content.length` as a third argument to the `$interval` function, `$interval(fn, delay, [count])`

Answer (score 0):

Update - This is working for me, not sure if it could be more efficient...

```
var time = 0;
var addLetter = function(i) {
    $scope.string2 = $scope.string.substr(0, i);
};
for (var i = 0, len = $scope.string.length; i < len + 1; i++) {
    time = time + 50;
    (function(time, i) {
        $timeout(function() {
            addLetter(i);
        }, (time));
    })(time, i);
}
```