# Hacker Typer Effect (reveal specific text on random key press) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to implement an effect similar to this [Hacker Typer](http://www.hackertyper.com/) site in AngularJS. I've based some of what I've got so far on the responses in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895718/angular-simple-typewriter-effect) but instead of using a timer I'm just counting up based on `ng-keyup`.

As it is now, each individual `ng-keyup` reveals a single character. But I'd like it to reveal three at once.

This is the approach I tried, but it seems to only reveal every third character. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="WriterCtrl" ng-keyup="ghostWriter()">
    <pre>KeyUps: {{count}}</pre>
    <p>{{typewritten}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('WriterCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var content = 'Mary Ann! Mary Ann! said the voice.';
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.typewritten = '';
    $scope.ghostWriter = function() {
      if ($scope.count < content.length) {
        $scope.typewritten = $scope.typewritten + content[$scope.count];
        $scope.count +=2;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for

http://plnkr.co/edit/QFPCP8aMKRyCsOuwNkcH?p=preview

```
//Content to be ghost written    
var content = "a whole load of content to be ghost written";

//Content already ghost written
$scope.typewritten = '';

//The ghost writer!
$scope.ghostWriter = function() {

  //If there is still content left to write
  if ($scope.typewritten.length < content.length) {

    //Write up to three characters from the remaining content
    $scope.typewritten += content.substr($scope.typewritten.length, 3);

  } else {

    window.alert('Writing time is over.');

  }

};
```

Comment: I found a little problem with this - if the `content.length` happens to be anything except for a multiple of 3, then it types out 'undefined' either once or twice at the end. I asked my friend about it and he proposed to use the `.substr()` method to set a maximum length like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5486Ri9zcV4KoCYw7lzg?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that is way better. I have updated the answer and the plunker. I also made it a bit shorter.